# Dropando dataframe em blocos e preenchendo valores no pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Preciso deduplicar uma base de dados, preservando alguns blocos de dados.

Tenho uma base com as colunas de Data, Chamada e Id, preciso implementar uma regra da seguinte forma:

- Toda regra B tem uma regra A anterior a ela.
- Toda regra C tem uma regra B anterior a ela.
- Preciso manter os últimos registros por bloco (Manter todos os A e aplicar as regras) de cada chamada.
- Substituir o Id faltante através das regras, ou seja, o Id da chamada B deve ser o Id da chamada A anterior a esta B.

| Data | Chamada | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09/03/2023 10:00:00 | A | 100 |
| 09/03/2023 11:00:00 | A | 100 |
| 09/03/2023 11:20:30 | B |  |
| 09/03/2023 11:45:00 | C | 100 |
| 09/03/2023 15:00:00 | A | 200 |
| 09/03/2023 17:25:00 | B |  |
| 09/03/2023 18:00:00 | A | 300 |
| 09/03/2023 19:00:00 | A | 400 |
| 09/03/2023 19:30:30 | A | 500 |
| 09/03/2023 21:00:00 | A | 600 |
| 09/03/2023 23:55:00 | A | 700 |
| 09/03/2023 23:56:00 | B |  |
| 09/03/2023 23:58:00 | C | 700 |
| 10/03/2023 09:00:00 | A | 800 |
| 10/03/2023 10:30:00 | B |  |
| 10/03/2023 11:30:00 | B |  |
| 10/03/2023 12:00:00 | B |  |
| 10/03/2023 13:30:00 | B |  |
| 10/03/2023 14:00:00 | B |  |
| 10/03/2023 14:30:00 | B |  |
| 10/03/2023 15:00:00 | A | 900 |
| 10/03/2023 16:00:00 | B |  |
| 10/03/2023 17:00:00 | C | 900 |

Ao aplicar as regras, o dataframe resultante seria o seguinte:

| Data | Chamada | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09/03/2023 11:00:00 | A | 100 |
| 09/03/2023 11:20:30 | B | 100 |
| 09/03/2023 11:45:00 | C | 100 |
| 09/03/2023 15:00:00 | A | 200 |
| 09/03/2023 17:25:00 | B | 200 |
| 09/03/2023 18:00:00 | A | 300 |
| 09/03/2023 19:00:00 | A | 400 |
| 09/03/2023 19:30:30 | A | 500 |
| 09/03/2023 21:00:00 | A | 600 |
| 09/03/2023 23:55:00 | A | 700 |
| 09/03/2023 23:56:00 | B | 700 |
| 09/03/2023 23:58:00 | C | 700 |
| 10/03/2023 09:00:00 | A | 800 |
| 10/03/2023 14:30:00 | B | 800 |
| 10/03/2023 15:00:00 | A | 900 |
| 10/03/2023 16:00:00 | B | 900 |
| 10/03/2023 17:00:00 | C | 900 |

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score -2):

Olha não sei se entendi bem o que você precisa.
Mas acho que isso deve ajudar em algo. É questão de você melhorar o caso que irá reconhecer quando você não tem o Id. Quando você reconhecer que ele esta 'branco'. Pegue o id do campo anterior.

Algo como:

```
import pandas as pd

frame = 'SEU DATA FRAME xd'

data = []
chamada = []
id = []
for i in range(0, frame.shape[0]):
    
    data.append(frame['Data'][i])
    chamada.append(frame['Chamada'][i])
    
    umid = frame['Id'][i]
    if umid == '':
        umid = frame['Id'][i-1]
    id.append(umid)
    
nova_tabela = pd.DataFrame({
    'Data': data,
    'Chamada': chamada,
    'Id': id
    })
```